# In what zone do the lingering effects of spells reside?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Cyclopean Tomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cyclopean%20Tomb), for example, creates an effect that continues for the rest of the game, even if it is destroyed.

Is there a name for the conceptual "board" of lingering effects whose originating cards are no longer on the battlefield?

Comment: Although it doesn't provide an answer, I think this article can at least provide some context for a good answer: [Oracle Review - Cyclopean Tomb and Gaea's Liege](http://humbabellasgamery.blogspot.com/2013/07/oracle-review-cyclopean-tomb-and-gaeas.html)

Comment: Note that many abilities function without the card ever having been on the battlefield. "Cycle" abilities, for example, work when the card is in your hand.

Comment: Note that continuous effects created by the resolution of spells and abilities last until the end of the game unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Consider explaining why it would be beneficial to have this question answered. Why is it important to know where these effects live?

Comment: Effects aren't objects, and thus they don't exist in any zone.

Answer (score 6):

They do not reside in any special realm. They just continue to apply. CR 611.2a states

> A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by
>   the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts until
>   the end of the game.

What is interesting is, that these effects continue to apply even if the controller of the spell or ability that generated it leaves the game in a multi-player. So, if you turned some of your opponent's lands into swamps and then are killed, those lands continue to be swamps as long as they remain on the battlefield with the counters. Since you already left the game, your turn will be skipped and no counters are removed by the tomb's second ability.

Answer (score -1):

Most cards with lingering effects have had their oracle text changed to include "emblems", which goes into the **Command Zone** (example: Elspeth, Knight-Errant), however the Cyclopean Tomb is not one of them (likely due to them being unused in competitive formats).

Because Cyclopean Tomb doesn't mention an emblem, Rule CR 611.2a would apply.

Here's a good article to read about this specific issue:

http://humbabellasgamery.blogspot.ca/2013/07/oracle-review-cyclopean-tomb-and-gaeas.html

Comment: Did any cards actually change to create emblems? Or do you just mean that's how they do it on new cards now?

Comment: @Rainbolt I explicitly state in my answer that Cyclopean Tomb doesn't include emblems, merely the effect is most similar to an emblem.
Jefromi, yes they changed some cards. One example is Elspeth, knight-Errant

Comment: @Othya the challenge in this question would be citing _why_ it gets treated as an emblem. If there's no rules around it at all, that's valuable to state. But it's also entirely possible that means these effects don't exist _anywhere_, they just _are._

Comment: @Rainbolt. Changed my answer a bit. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I seem to recall Stigma Lasher getting errata about emblems at one point, but if it ever did, it's back to its original wording now. For the time being, emblems are produced exclusively by planeswalkers.

Comment: This answer is misleading. Continuous effects do not exist in any zone and they are not the same as emblems. Emblems are *objects* with *abilities* that create *effects*, they are not themselves effects.

Comment: @Jefromi, I believe Elspeth, Knight Errant is the only card to have a "for the rest of the game" ability changed into an emblem.